# Backbone Layout Manager Nested Views not rendering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-layout-manager, nested-views

I am using Backbone and the Backbone Layout Manager plugin. I am trying to render a view which contains a nested view.

```
var ContentView = Backbone.Layout.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'container',

    views: {
        "contactList": new ContactListView({
                            collection: new Contacts()
                        })
    },

    changeContactSelection: function(one){
        console.log('dsdssdsdssd');
        console.log(one);
    },

    initialize: function (){
        this.listenTo(this.getView("contactList"), "change:selectedContact", this.changeContactSelection);
    }
});
```

This code runs with no errors but nothing is rendered on the screen. I have also tried adding

```
beforeRender: function (){
    this.insertView("contactList");
}
```

but this causes the following error

> **Uncaught Error:** The argument associated with selector `'contactList'` is defined and a View.  Set `manage` property to `true` for `Backbone.View` instances

However, `ContactListView` is a `Backbone.Layout`, not a `Backbone.View`.

Comment: Layout is extended from Backbone.View

Comment: I know that but usually the above error occurs when the view extends Backbone.View, but seeing as my class extends Backbone.Layout the error does not make sense

Comment: Given that your class extends Backbone.Layout and Layout is extended from Backbone.View, your class extends Backbone.View.